# Changing default WPMU emails to be send thorugh Campaign Monitor Transactional emails

Tags: php, email, notifications

I am trying to use CM transactional emails to work with wordpress default emails on WPMU installation. So far I've found the required hooks to do this, but i have a few questions.

```
add_action('init', function() {
    remove_action('register_new_user', 'wp_send_new_user_notifications');
    remove_action('network_site_new_created_user', 'wp_send_new_user_notifications');
    remove_action('network_site_users_created_user', 'wp_send_new_user_notifications');
    remove_action('network_user_new_created_user', 'wp_send_new_user_notifications');
    remove_action('edit_user_created_user', 'wp_send_new_user_notifications');

add_action('register_new_user', 'ES_send_new_user_notifications');
});
```

I'm using `remove_action` to remove default notifications, but I am not sure how to get additional information about the user in `ES_send_new_user_notifications`

```
function ES_send_new_user_notifications($user_id, $notify = 'user') {   
    // I need blog id to which user is registered 
    // I need password in plain text to be available
    // then send everything to Campaign Monitor to be delivered to user
}
```

All those hooks have `user_id` available as parameter.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: _I need password in plain text_ Why?

Comment: So I can send it to the user via transactional email.

Comment: It's a very bad idea to send the password in plain text by email even email is secured . The good idea is to sent users the temporary valid-only-once link to change their default passwords.